# Add missing Constraints not doing its job properly

Tags: ios, xcode, autolayout, constraints

This is what I see on my storyboard.

[image]

This is what I see in the simulator (iPhone6)

[image]

I added constraints by doing "clear constraints" -> "add missing constraints."

**Q.** How come add missing constraints did not properly align the boxes in the middle, and how do I solve this problem?

**Update:** the problem hasn't been resolved even after width constraints.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Clear constraints, add constraints for the element you want then Add Missing Contraints. It will leave the contraints you added intact

Answer (score 1):

I never trust IB to add missing constraints for me. It doesn't know our intention and most of the time it has to guess. In this case, it guessed that you needed the orange boxes to take 300pt width (because the prototype view is 600pt wide). And it guessed that you wanted the blue part to takes the rest which is only 75pt on iPhone 6. It didn't know if you want the orange boxes to take half the space or just 300pt. Craft your constraints manually if you think there might be some ambiguities in your intention.

### To solve the problem, do one of the following:

- Make the trailing edge of the orange boxes align to the center of the container view. And the leading edge of the blue box align to the center of the container view.
- Make an equal width constraint for the top orange box and the blue box. And make the horizontal spacing between them equal to zero.

This gif visually explains my second approach.

[image: Adding Constraints]

Comment: After settings the width constraints, the problem still persists.

Comment: First remove all the existing horizontal constraints for those three boxes. Then `ctrl` drag from the left box to the right box and choose `Equal Width`. Then make sure that `constant` is set to `0`. Make left edge and right edge constraint for those boxes.

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add constraints with right bottom menu in storyboard.Just tick the height and weight boxes:[image]